# ASP.NET MVC - How to DisAllow logged in user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 4. When we build a project, they add an `AccountController` by default. You can create an acoount and log in right away...  but after they've logged in, try to type `http://localhost:port/Account/LogOn`.  You still stay at the Login page with the login form.

I have tried to redirect the user by using this code:

```
    //
    // GET: /Account/LogOn
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {

        if(Membership.GetUser().UserName != null)
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        return ContextDependentView();
    }
```

The code works fine until I log out, and then this code no longer works.  Please show me the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to copy over the rights-chechking code - do write a filter instead and use it multiple times with no code duplication.

```
public class GuestsOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext )
    {
        if( User.Identity.IsAuthenticated )
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "RestrictedArea" };
        }
    }
}
```

In your controller

```
// GET: /Account/LogOn
[GuestsOnly]
public ActionResult LogOn() { ... }
```

Comment: This is not a particularly smart approach. His question first of all is about redirecting based on whether the user is authenticated, and second, if you are going to batten down the hatches for authorization it is much smarter to take a `white-list filter` approach and lock down all your controllers with a BaseController inherited.

Comment: Redirecting is very easy: there was a class like RedirectResult. Assign it to filterContext.Result and you've got a redirect.
So why are filters less smart than introducing a BaseController?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed:

```
//
// GET: /Account/LogOn
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult LogOn()
{

    if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else 
    {
        return ContextDependentView();
    }
}
```